# 403 Error on ASP.NET/ AngularJS App Load

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, http-status-code-403

I've had this asp.net/angularJS app that uses windows authentication for awhile now, and have had no real problems with it until now. Until like an hour ago it was working fine, then out of nowhere I started getting the 403 error "The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.". The main problem now seems that it isn't behaving like an angular application anymore when it comes to routing. I've tried setting the directory browsing to true, but it just took me to a schema of my project. Anyone run into something similar or no how to resolve this issue?

In addition here is my web config
    
    
    
      
        
        
      
      
        
        
        
        
      
      http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

```
    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <globalization culture="en-US" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <identity impersonate="false" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" maxQueryStringLength="10240" enable="true" />
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <!--<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>-->
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: How is ASP.net involved in loading your angular application? Are you just using Web API and asp.net has nothing to do with loading your app or are you loading angular in a MVC view?

Comment: I'm loading angular in an MVC view

Comment: What resource being called (and by "who") when that error occurs? On the containing view (the page containing the app) or is it something your Angular app requests? Do all other asp.net pages/views exhibit the same (403)?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't appear to be an angular issue at all. It looks like Asp.net MVC routing is not running. You should check your web.config and see if you have something like this in there. If not you need to add it.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Edit: You need to add the ExtensionlessUrlHandler back in there. Sorry my first example was a litte sparse.

Comment: Hmm I tried inserting it and it was still giving me the same 403.14 error

Comment: can you post your web.config? just make sure you remove any sensitive data first.

Comment: I just posted my web config minus my authentication and connection strings

Comment: Could it be because I have a newer version of .net on my machine that what the project is running on? There were some windows updates that were applied I think either yesterday or early this morning

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate everyone that took the time to try and help me out. After doing some digging I realized my Global.asax file had been deleted. Visual Studio Web has been running real slow and I must have accidentally deleted it somehow, but bring back that file ended up solving the issue!